Implement a server and client communicating via sockets in Python
I need to implement a server and client communicating via sockets in Python. I decided to implement the server with asyncio.start_server. Clients connect to the server with socket connections. The server generates some messages at random moments and immediately pushes those messages to the client. All clients should receive the same messages as soon as possible and print them.
My implementation of server:
import asyncio
import datetime as dt
import struct
import sys

from random import randrange
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo


async def prepare_weather_data():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(randrange(0, 7))

        now = dt.datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Europe/Kyiv")).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
        massage = f"{now} The temperature is {str(randrange(20, 30))} degrees Celsius"

        message_encoded = massage.encode()
        message_length = struct.pack('>I', len(message_encoded))

        yield message_length + message_encoded


async def read_massage(reader: asyncio.StreamReader):
    # Read the 4-byte length header
    length_data = await reader.readexactly(4)
    message_length = struct.unpack('>I', length_data)[0]
    message_encoded = await reader.readexactly(message_length)
    return message_encoded.decode()


async def handle_client(
    _: asyncio.StreamReader,
    writer: asyncio.StreamWriter,
    weather_data: bytes,
):
    try:
        writer.write(weather_data)
        await writer.drain()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Closing the connection")
        writer.close()
        sys.exit(0)


async def main():
    async def client_handler(reader, writer):
        message = await read_massage(reader)
        print(f"Received the message \"{message}\" that won't be handled any way")

        async for weather_data in prepare_weather_data():
            await handle_client(reader, writer, weather_data)

    server = await asyncio.start_server(client_handler, "localhost", 8000)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

The client:
import sys
import socket
import struct


def recvall(sock: socket.socket, n: int) -> bytes | None:
    # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = bytearray()
    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None
        data.extend(packet)
    return data


def read_massage(sock: socket.socket) -> str | None:
    # Read the 4-byte length
    message_length_encoded = recvall(sock, 4)
    if not message_length_encoded:
        print("Socket closed")
        sys.exit(0)

    message_length = struct.unpack('>I', message_length_encoded)[0]
    return recvall(sock, message_length).decode()


so = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET,
    socket.SOCK_STREAM,
)

so.connect(("localhost", 8000))  # Blocking
print("Connected")

try:
    message = "Hello, give me a weather, please".encode()

    # Pack the length of the message into 4 bytes (big-endian)
    message_length = struct.pack('>I', len(message))
    sent = so.send(message_length + message)  # Blocking
    print(f"Sent {sent} bytes")

    while True:
        msg = read_massage(so)
        print(msg)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    so.close()
    print("Socket closed")
    sys.exit(0)

This version of the server generally works. The server generates messages and pushes them to the clients. However, all clients receive different messages! How to modify the server to push the same message to all clients? I tried everything I could.
UPD
I see two possible approaches.

Store generated data in some container accessible to all clients.
Like this:
 async def handle_client(reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter, weather_data):
     _ = await read_message(reader)
     try:
         while True:
             async for data in weather_data:
                 writer.write(data)
             await writer.drain()
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print("Closing the connection")
         writer.close()
         sys.exit(0)

 async def main():
     weather_data = prepare_weather_data()

     async def client_handler(reader, writer):
         await handle_client(reader, writer, weather_data)

     server = await asyncio.start_server(client_handler, "localhost", 8000)
     async with server:
         await server.serve_forever()



However, it crashes for the second connected client as asynchronous generator is already running.

Register all connected clients and push generated data to them. I tried getting all connected clients as asyncio.all_tasks(). However, I didn't get how to use it.


"I tried everything I could." - which says absolutely nothing what you actually tried. Since you generare a new random message for each call of prepare_weather_data and you call prepare_weather_data for each new client you get a new random message for each client. If you don't want this you should not generate a new random message.

The first idea was to place handle_client into the loop:
    `for _ in range(len(asyncio.all_tasks()) - 1):`

However, it doesn't work

I added a possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/79077314/4388451 and would be grateful for your comments.

The server part may be changed in the following way:
import asyncio
import datetime as dt
import struct

from random import randrange
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

writers = []
all_writers = {}
weather = b''


async def prepare_weather_data(t):
    global weather, writers
    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(randrange(0, 7))
            now = dt.datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Europe/Kyiv")).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
            message = f"{now} The temperature is {str(randrange(20, 30))} degrees Celsius"

            message_encoded = message.encode()
            message_length = struct.pack('>I', len(message_encoded))

            weather = message_length + message_encoded

            writers = []
            print(message)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        t.cancel()


async def read_message(reader: asyncio.StreamReader):
    # Read the 4-byte length header
    length_data = await reader.readexactly(4)
    message_length = struct.unpack('>I', length_data)[0]
    message_encoded = await reader.readexactly(message_length)
    return message_encoded.decode()


async def handle_client(
    writer: asyncio.StreamWriter,
):
    socname = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    try:
        while True:
            # todo: refactor to avoid sleep
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            if socname not in writers:
                writers.append(socname)
                writer.write(weather)
                await writer.drain()
    except* ConnectionResetError:
        del all_writers[socname]
        writer.close()
        print(f'Socket {socname} closed')
    except* asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass
    except* Exception as e:
        print(f'ERROR: {str(e)}')
        raise e


async def client_handler(reader, writer):
    socname = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    all_writers[socname] = writer
    message = await read_message(reader)
    print(f"Socket {socname} connected. Received message: \"{message}\"")
    await handle_client(writer)


async def run_server():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(client_handler, "localhost", 8000)
    print(f'Serving on {server.sockets[0].getsockname()}')
    async with server:
        try:
            await server.serve_forever()
        finally:
            for writer in all_writers.values():
                writer.close()

async def main():
    try:
        async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as group:
            t = group.create_task(run_server())
            group.create_task(prepare_weather_data(t))
    except* asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('Stopped by user')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

It is not a perfect solution, but it is a working one. From my point of view, it may be improved if

avoid the coroutines switch await asyncio.sleep(0)
avoid global variables usage as much as possible
avoid explicitly canceling the task with t.cancel(); add the exception-raising task as it is recommended in the documentation
eliminate the ~2-second delay in notifying client disconnections on the server side; i.e. the delay in printing f'Socket {socname} closed'

I tried improving the script but haven't found working improvements yet. I would be grateful for any ideas.

I prefer having all the client handling inside one single function, so I think that having an external generator is more complex than useful. Additionaly I prefer to explicitely handle all expected exceptions: that way, the server can count how many clients are connected and the clients are immediately notified when the server is closed. Finaly, as you said that you would prefer avoid global variables (to observe best practices...), I have used a closure. The server module has become:
import asyncio
import datetime as dt
import struct
import sys

from random import randrange
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo


async def prepare_weather_data():
    serial = 0
    nxt = dt.datetime.now()
    message = ''
    total = 0

    def set_message():
        nonlocal message, serial, nxt

        now = dt.datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Europe/Kyiv")).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
        message = f"{now} The temperature is {str(randrange(20, 30))} degrees Celsius"
        message_encoded = message.encode()
        message_length = struct.pack('>I', len(message_encoded))
        message = message_length + message_encoded
        serial += 1
        if serial == 1024:
            serial = 1
        nxt = dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(seconds=randrange(0, 7))
        
    async def handle_client(
        reader: asyncio.StreamReader,
        writer: asyncio.StreamWriter):
        
        nonlocal serial, nxt, message, total

        total += 1
        msg = await read_massage(reader)
        print(f"Received the message \"{msg}\" that won't be handled any way")
        print(f"Currently: {total} client(s)")
        
        if serial == 0:
            set_message()

        try:
            while True:
                loc = serial
                writer.write(message)
                await writer.drain()
                await asyncio.sleep(max((nxt-dt.datetime.now()).total_seconds(), 0))
                if loc == serial:
                    set_message()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)
        except ConnectionError:
            total -= 1
            print(f"Currently: {total} client(s)")
        except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
            total -= 1
            print(f"Currently: {total} client(s)")
        except BaseException as e:
            print(type(e), e)
            return

    return handle_client


async def read_massage(reader: asyncio.StreamReader):
    # Read the 4-byte length header
    length_data = await reader.readexactly(4)
    message_length = struct.unpack('>I', length_data)[0]
    message_encoded = await reader.readexactly(message_length)
    return message_encoded.decode()



async def main():
    client_handler = await prepare_weather_data()
    server = await asyncio.start_server(client_handler, "localhost", 8000)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)


Alternatively, you could use a plain object instead of a closure. The good news is that it will be easier to respect a separation of concern between the generation of the weather data (inside the object) and the handling of the clients (inside a dedicated coroutine). Code could be:
import asyncio
import datetime as dt
import struct
import sys

from random import randrange
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo


class Weather_data_builder():
    def __init__(self, ready: asyncio.Event):
        self.total = 0
        self.serial: int = 0
        self.message: bytes = b''
        asyncio.create_task(self.gather_data(ready))

    def set_message(self):
        now = dt.datetime.now(ZoneInfo("Europe/Kyiv")).replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
        message = f"{now} The temperature is {str(randrange(20, 30))} degrees Celsius"
        message_encoded = message.encode()
        message_length = struct.pack('>I', len(message_encoded))
        self.message = message_length + message_encoded
        self.serial += 1
        if self.serial == 1024:
            self.serial = 0
        timeout = randrange(0, 7)
        self.nxt = dt.datetime.now() + dt.timedelta(seconds=timeout)
        return timeout
        
    async def gather_data(self, ready: asyncio.Event):
        timeout = self.set_message()
        ready.set()
        try:
            while True:
                await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
                timeout = self.set_message()
        except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
            return

    async def get_data(self, serial:int = None):
        if serial == self.serial:
            await asyncio.sleep((self.nxt - dt.datetime.now()).total_seconds())
            while self.serial == serial:
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
        return self.serial, self.message


async def read_massage(reader: asyncio.StreamReader):
    # Read the 4-byte length header
    length_data = await reader.readexactly(4)
    message_length = struct.unpack('>I', length_data)[0]
    message_encoded = await reader.readexactly(message_length)
    return message_encoded.decode()


async def get_builder():
    ready = asyncio.Event()
    builder = Weather_data_builder(ready)
    await ready.wait()
    return builder


async def main():
    builder = await get_builder()
    total = 0
    
    async def handle_client(
        reader: asyncio.StreamReader,
        writer: asyncio.StreamWriter,
        ):
        
        nonlocal builder, total
        
        total += 1
        msg = await read_massage(reader)
        print(f"Received the message \"{msg}\" that won't be handled any way")
        print(f"Currently: {total} client(s)")
        
        serial = None
        try:
            while True:
                serial, message = await builder.get_data(serial)
                await writer.drain()
                writer.write(message)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit(0)
        except ConnectionError:
            total -= 1
            print(f"Currently {total} client(s)")
        except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
            total -= 1
            print(f"Currently: {total} client(s)")
        except BaseException as e:
            print(type(e), e)
            return


    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, "localhost", 8000)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)

